# Share to multiple friends walls on Facebook from my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I will try to be as clear as I can with my request but as I am still unsure as to what I am looking for I might come across as vague.

I was hoping I could get some help understanding the best approach to allowing a user to post a link with an attached image to the walls of a selection of their friends on Facebook. There are lot of approaches and answers out there but I am having trouble determining what is best.

Thanks for helping me see straight

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really up to the user if your using the JS toolkit.

Click share under your question. Then when dialog pops up you get the option of where to share it.

So solution 1) leave it in the hands of the user.

If you want to force them into share on friends wall you will need to find something that does this or 
DIY.

The DIY approach would be to have your site /app do oAuth authentication. Pass that to an oauth library and then list a users friends maybe with https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector.

Then issue the appropriate graph request to post to each one's time line.

The choice is yours but those are the 2 approaches I know of.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have been able to get facebook javascript sdk working on my site and posting to user walls.